# If I enter a non integer value in input, code suddenly malfunctions

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, while-loop, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

void number_checker(int n);

int main(void) {

    int a, b; 

    while (1) {

        printf("Digit checker\n");

        printf("\nEnter the character: ");

        scanf("%d", &a); 

        number_checker(a);

        printf("\nIf you want to continue press 1\n");

        scanf("%d", &b);

        if (b == 1) {

            continue;

        } else {

            printf("Thanks for using");

            break; 
        }

        return 0;
    }
}

void number_checker(int n) {

    if (n >= 0 && n <= 9) {

        printf("\nEntered character is a digit\n");

    } else {

        printf("\nEntered character is not a digit\n");

    }
}
```

[image]

It works fine for integers but stuck in loop for other characters, I want to know why it is going forever

Comment: It isn't so much a coding error as the way `scanf()` is designed to work: unprocessable input remains in the buffer. One strategy is not to use `scanf()` but `fgets()` followed by `sscanf()`. If the input is incorrect, it can easily be forgotten and repeated. One thing that will help you is *always check* the value that the `scanf` function  family returns. Here it must be `1`,  the number of inputs successfully processed. So `if(scanf("%d",&a) != 1)`

Answer (score 4):

`scanf("%d", &a)` skips any white space characters from standard input, then attempts to read digits and converts them to an `int` value it stores into `a`.

If you type a number with a decimal point, `scanf()` will stop at the decimal point, which is not a digit, and returns `1` if there was at least one digit before the `.`, storing the `int` value into `a`.

The subsequent call `scanf("%d", &b)` finds the pending `.` and fails to convert an `int`, leaves `b` unchanged, ie: uninitialized, and returns `0` to indicate it could not perform a single conversion.

The loop goes on, and every call to `scanf()` fails the same way without any character being consumed from standard input.  This explains your observations.

Instead of using `scanf()` directly, you should read the input one line at a time and use `sscanf()` to attempt the conversion, check the return value and report any invalid or missing input.

You should check the return value of `scanf()` to detect invalid or missing input.

Note also that `%d` reads and converts a whole number (pun intended), not just a single digit, so the test in function `number_checker()` is somewhat inappropriate.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void number_checker(int n);

int main(void) {
    char buf[80];
    int a, b, len; 

    printf("Digit checker\n\n");

    for (;;) {
        printf("Enter the character: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%d%n", &a, &len) == 0) {
            printf("not a number: %s\n", buf);
            continue;
        }
        if (buf[len] != '\n') {
            printf("extra characters: %s\n", buf + len);
            continue;
        }

        number_checker(a);

        printf("If you want to continue press 1\n");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;

        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &b) == 1 && b == 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("Thanks for using");
    return 0;
}

void number_checker(int n) {
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 9) {
        printf("Number entered is a single digit\n");
    } else {
        printf("Number entered has multiple digits or is negative\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By input you mean `scanf("%d", &a)` and `scanf("%d", &b)` the reason why non-integer results to `error` is due to the fact the `%d` specifier in the `scanf` function reads specifically round numbers. It would not even read `float` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It malfunctions because you can not store a non-`int` value in an `int` variable. C compilers always check types.
To overcome this, you first need to put it inside a `char array` then detect if it's a number, only then store it in an `int` variable..

Shortcut: `scanf` function returns **1** if it receives a number.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int number;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    if (scanf("%d", &number) == 1) {
        printf("Input is a valid integer. Stored value: %d\n", number);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input. Please enter an integer.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```